# Mac OSX Sierra Upgrade to latest Apache version

Tags: macos, apache

I would like to be running the latest version of Apache on my MacBook PHP dev machine.

Since the upgrade to Sierra it is now at 2.4.23 which seems to be the most current. But that will likely change. When it does, is it possible to upgrade to the newest on the Mac? If so, how please?
Thanks
Mark

Answer (score 0):

Update will come with the next upgrade of Mac OS. In this case, you can see this page: https://jason.pureconcepts.net/2016/09/update-apache-php-mysql-mac-os-x-sierra/

Apache is part of the OS and updates of this will be provided by App store of with software upgrades.

Alternative is using MacPorts. https://www.macports.org/

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to stay up to date with the PHP part (and not Apache itself), you could take a look here: https://php-osx.liip.ch/